# How can i join the above statement to my below statement into one sql statement

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

This is my average rating statement
SELECT AVG(rating) from `review` left join `restaurant` on review.restaurant_id = restaurant.restaurant_id where restaurant_name = "Genki Sushi";

Whereby This is my get all restaurant statement.
SELECT * FROM mydb.restaurant, region_category where restaurant.region_id = region_category.region_id order by restaurant_id;

I want to combine that average rating into my get all restaurant statement.[this is the image of my er diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjKJZ.png).Helppp

Answer (score 0):

You need to join your reviews to your restaurant. In your ER you have `restaurant_id` in `review` so you can use it like in the code below.

If you're using MySQL 8.0 or above this should work.

```
    with avgreview as (
select review.restaurant_id, AVG(rating) from review left join restaurant on review.restaurant_id = restaurant.restaurant_id where restaurant_name = 'Genki Sushi'
  group by 1
)   
select * from restaurant r 
inner join region_category rc 
on r.region_id = rc.region_id
left join avgreview ar 
on r.restaurant_id = ar.restaurant_id
order by r.restaurant_id
```